# How to backup Windows folder only?

Tags: windows-backup, incremental-backup

I am low in HDD space and I use my C: drive for my other files too. On the other hand, I want to be able to periodically backup windows folder (preferably using a differential/incremental backup solution).

Considering that Windows folder contains symbolic links and junction points, what are some solutions for doing the above?
Since I am low in HDD space, I don't want to use a disk imaging solution like Norton Ghost.

Comment: Can you use the backup function of Windows?

Comment: back up function of Windows takes an image of drive C and I don't want that.

Comment: Backing up to the same hard drive is asking for trouble.  If you hard drive goes back the likelihood of recovering your "backup" whatever method you use will likely be unrecoverable.  Please invest in an external or second hard drive if your backups really matter.

Comment: I am backing up to an external HDD. I just don't want to backup all of drive C:

Comment: Low disk space on other drives too. Besides, I don't want to backup program files and users folders.

Comment: Backing up just the Windows folder won’t provide you anything that can be used to restore your system if it can’t boot. Creating a disk image of your disk is the only viable solution.

Comment: I am quite tech-savvy and can work my way around those issues, but my only concern right now is this.

Comment: You really should go for the disk image approach, like @Ramhound suggested. I don't think there even exists 3rd party applications that can do this. In Linux you can accomplish what you desire. In Windows, not so much.